# Arrays, foreach, adding string to array trouble

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

```
if ($_POST['op_ep_cat'] == 'op_single_ep') 
{
$ep_place = $_POST['the_place']; 
$eps_array = array();   
    array_push($eps_array, $ep_place); 
}

else if ($_POST['op_ep_cat'] == 'op_category') {
    $cat_site = $_POST['the_place'];    
    $taken_cat_site = file_get_contents($cat_site);

    if (preg_match_all('#<div class="content_ep"><a href="(.+?)"#si', $taken_cat_site, $eps_array));

    else if (preg_match_all('#<div class="postlist">\s*<a href="(.+?)"#si', $taken_cat_site, $eps_array));

}


foreach(array_reverse($eps_array[1]) as $eps_match)
{ 
     echo 'Arughh!';
}
```

The above works for the `'op_category'` perfectly, but not for the `'op_single_ep'`... So basically `$ep_place` needs to be apart of the `$eps_array[1]`, if possible, somehow.. Hopefully any of this makes sense!

I appreciate any help!

Comment: can you try elaborate your problem further? xD

Comment: You havent provided what exactly isn't working.
do a print_r of your $_POST and $eps_array to see the problem

Comment: Adding `print_r($eps_array);` below the preg_push produces: `Array ( [0] => http://xxxxx.com/xxxx )` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that

```
$eps_array = array(1 => array($_POST['the_place']));
```

but whole code is just weird

Answer (score 1):

`$eps_array[1]` is not array, is element of `$eps_array`
You can make array

```
$eps_array = array(1=>array());
array_push($eps_array[1], $ep_place);
```

Try to read [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) about What is array

Comment: That worked! I would not have been able to create that even if I read the whole manual. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it'd be `$eps_array[0]` for the `op_single_ep` version. Remember, PHP arrays have 0-based indexes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if ($_POST['op_ep_cat'] == 'op_single_ep') 
{
  $ep_place = $_POST['the_place'];  
  $eps_array = array();
  $eps_array[1] = array();
  array_push($eps_array[1], $ep_place); 
}
```

Comment: aha, forgot to set eps_array[1] = array(); :)

Comment: Tried that, and got: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array, array_reverse() [function.array-reverse]: The argument should be an array, Invalid argument supplied for foreach()... Oh, hmm..